# MySQL & PHP : Time() to Decimal Hour

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have in my MySQL database two Time() saves: start and end.

I would like to have a decimal result of the interval between my two times in my PHP code.

```
for exemple, if :

start = 15:00:00
end = 16:00:00
result = 1

and if 

start = 15:30:00
end = 16:00:00
result = 0,5
```

Is it possible to get this result using MySQL? If it isn't possible, how could I convert a time format to decimal interval please?

Thanks a lot for reading my issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for any guides? Show us that you've made an effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: Well i tried timediff SQL function, but the results given are a little incoherent so I think this is not the best situation to use timediff.

Then I used TIMESTAMPDIFF but the result was always 0.

Then I created a PHP function to convert dates, but my function is not really ok because it dont takes Seconds. That's why I came here to know if anyone had a solution already improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very straightforward solution would be to take this two values, convert them to time and then make it to hours.

```
$start = "15:00:00";
$end = "16:00:00";

$result = (strtotime($end) - strtotime($start))/3600;
```

That gives you `$result =  1`

For values `15:30:00` and `16:00:00` `$result` will be `0.5`.

Comment: I'm going to try to modify my function to use strtotime, thanks, i'll tell you if it worked for me.

Comment: No problem. I think my solution is the simplest way you can do it in php

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

So I think it is easy. Just follow these steps:

1. You need to separate those numbers. Make 3 variables. For this example we'll use $hours, $minutes, $seconds (you can achieve these by separating the main time using REGEX. I recommend reading about how to do it first)
2. Now you have these numbers, for example like so:

   $start = "15:30:00";
   $start_hours = "15"
   $start_minutes = "30"; //or just 0
   $start_seconds = "00"; //or just 0

   $end = "16:00:00";
   $end_hours = "15"
   $end_minutes = "00"; //or just 0
   $end_seconds = "00"; //or just 0

So... this is briefly how you need to separate those numbers.

3. Now about the counting...

   $result_hours = $end_hours - $start_hours //there you get 1

So hours are easy... For the minutes we need to think about time it self. Cause time values are always in 60 and we need "percents" which are in 100. We'll solve this doing:

```
$result_minutes = $end_minutes + $start_minutes; //you get 30.. which obviously is NOT what we want.. easily fixed by://

$right_minutes = 100 / 60 * $result_minutes; // gives you 50, which is great.
```

So far, we have 1,50 (If you'll take enough effort you can simply devide 50 by 10.. you'll get 5)

```
$result_seconds = $end_seconds + $start_seconds;
$right_seconds = 100 / 60 * $result_seconds;
```

Now we need to realize that we are dealing with seconds, so the number will be percentage of MINUTES not hours, we can fix this using:

```
$best_seconds = 100 / 60 * (0.$right_seconds) //now we have all right.

$right = $right_minutes + $best_seconds;

$result = $result_hours.",".$right;
```

.........................

And that should be it. Hope it will help you figure out the best solution, this is just how I thought it might work.

Try. Change. Try. And Done.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks a lot, your demonstration is really helpfull and clear. I've modified my code to follow your steps

Comment: Could we speak on a tchat please? I have another question

Comment: @shqnks yeah, of corse, how?

Comment: I thought that in Stackoverflow we could open a tchat for a question, but I can't find where

Comment: @shqnks yeah, I don't know either... :/

Comment: do you know discord?

Comment: @shqnks not really, what is it?

Comment: https://discord.gg/9FGDr you can click there it's a channel where we can discuss (i deactivate the mic tho)

Comment: @shqnks well, I am on iOS and there are several problems.. but I can simply give you my Facebook, why not..

Comment: Ok i'll add you

Comment: can't find you. this is my facebook, as soon as you contact me, i'll delete this message.
xxx